# How to align divs horizontally withput letting them fall down when the page border is reached?

Tags: html, css

I have this problem. I would like to create a page showing/displaying a series of items in horizontal flow. It means that I want them to align horizontally, but they have to stay in a horizontal line even if they reach the border of the page (yes, I want the horizontal scrollbar to eventually display, it does not bother me, on the contrary, it is needed.).

NOTE:
Please, accordingly to recent design models, please I would like to avoid using tables... just divs...

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Place them all inside a `white-space:nowrap` container.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the elements inside the `white-space: nowrap;` container are inline/inline-block elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <style type="text/css">
 .container {white-space:nowrap; height: 20px; }
 .content{float:left;border: 1px solid black; width:100px;}
 </style>

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $().ready(function() {
    var containerwidth =0;
    $(".content").each(function(){containerwidth = containerwidth +$(this).width()+10;});
    $(".container").width(containerwidth );
    });
 </script>

 <div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
 etc.
 </div>
```

Comment: It does not work :( Firefox latest version on OS Snow Leopard :(

Comment: oops - my test code didn't have divs! Corrected to use jQuery to set container width - will now handle div content blocks. Maybe there's another way though?

Comment: my solution uses jQuery - do you have a reference to this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Senad will still wrap if you reduced the width of the browser window.

What you want is **`white-space:nowrap;`** in your css so that text is not wrapped

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Element</li>
  <li>Element</li>
  .
  .
  .
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I need to go now, i'll check it later :) thanks